# CakePHP associations: how to retrieve all hasMany associations the proper way?

Tags: cakephp, model

As a newbie to CakePHP I’m really struggling to understand how CakePHP’s associations (and basically the whole MVC) work, even after reading a lot of tutorials and documentation.

I have three models, layered as follows:

```
class User extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany = array('Album');
}

class Album extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array('User');
  public $hasMany = array('Photo');
}

class Photo extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array('Album');
}
```

I have a `$user = $this->Auth->user()` which seems more like an Array than an object. 
Although CakePHP seems really clever with automagically doing stuff for you, `$user->getAlbums()` and than a `->getPhotos();` on that object doesn’t seem to return anything.
My question: how do I retrieve in a clever way the Albums of the authed user, and the Photos which are in an Album?

Comment: where are the methods `getAlbums` and `getPhotos` defined?

Comment: Good point. Actually nowhere, I would think that CakePHP has some sort of automagical method for that, since I also specify $hasMany.

Comment: It does have methods for finding things - namely [find](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find). If you want to create methods such as `get*` you can do that but it requires you to create them - "automagically" doesn't mean "make stuff up and hope it works" =). It would be wise to develop with debug on and/or read the error log (`app/tmp/logs/error.log`) it'll be full of sql errors as undefined methods are passed to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

**how do I retrieve in a clever way the Albums of the authed user**

Try this in your `UsersController` class :

```
$albums = $this->User->Album->findByUserId($this->Auth->user('id'));
```

**...and the Photos which are in an Album?**

As a benefit, queries by Cakephp get data from joined models... e.g :

```
debug($albums);


[0] => Array
        (
            [Album] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [titre] => Premier Album
                    [contenu] => aaa
                    [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                )
            [Photo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [album_id] => 1
                            [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [album_id] => 1
                            [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                        )
                )
```

However, if your resulting array grows too big, you should take a look at the great [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)